# sqrt() returning INF

Tags: c, math.h, sqrt

Hi I'm trying to do some calculations with long doubles and I am getting INF from sqrt() function.

Code:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    long double bigNUMBER;
    long double p1,p2,p3;
    long double p4;

    p1 = 4.769547e+155;
    p2 = 1.012994e+170;
    p3 = 1.714812e+169;

    p4 = p1*p1 + p2*p2 + p3*p3;

    bigNUMBER = sqrt(p4);

    printf("product: %Lf\n\n", p4); // 1055562645989439942507809393771156765931135...

    printf("\n result %Lf\n\n", bigNUMBER); // INF

    return 0;
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`sqrt` takes and returns a `double`. When you call it, your `long double` will be converted in a `double` which cannot store such a big number, and will thus get the value of infinity.

Use `sqrtl` that takes and returns a `long double`.

Comment: Worked fine! But I found no references for sqrtl(), is it a standard function?

Comment: @Murilo: yes, at least for C99.

Comment: From the `sqrtf`, `sqrt`, and `sqrtl` man page, it apparently is standard by C99 and POSIX.1-2001.

Comment: But not C89 -- only `sqrt` is defined for C89.

Answer (score 2):

`sqrt` will return `INFINITY` when the argument is `INFINITY` as well; e.g.:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
  printf("%g %g\n", INFINITY, sqrt(INFINITY));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: But the argument is not INFINITY.

Comment: Actually, it is. When a number too large to represent in double gets cast to double, it becomes INFINITY.